# Why is accessing a memory aligned buffer more expensive in Linux?

Tags: c, performance, memory-alignment

In the below program, I have 2 buffers, one which is 64byte aligned and another, which I am assuming is 16 byte aligned on my 64 Linux host running 2.6.x kernel.

The cache line is 64byte long. So, in this program, I simply access one cache line at a time. I was hoping to see `posix_memaligned` to be equal if not faster than the non aligned buffer. 
Here are some metrics

```
./readMemory 10000000

time taken by posix_memaligned buffer: 293020299 
time taken by standard buffer: 119724294 

./readMemory 100000000

time taken by posix_memaligned buffer: 548849137 
time taken by standard buffer: 211197082
```

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

void now(struct timespec * t);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{        
  char *buf;        
  struct timespec st_time, end_time;        
  int runs;        
  if (argc !=2) 
  {
             printf("Usage: ./readMemory <number of runs>\n");                
             exit(1);        
  }        
  errno = 0;        
  runs = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);        
  if (errno !=0)        {
            printf("Invalid number of runs: %s \n", argv[1]);
            exit(1);
    }

    int returnVal = -1;

    returnVal = posix_memalign((void **)&buf, 64, 1024);
    if (returnVal != 0)
    {
            printf("error in posix_memaligh\n");
    }

    char tempBuf[64];
    char * temp = buf;

    size_t cpyBytes = 64;

    now(&st_time);
    for(int x=0; x<runs; x++) {
    temp = buf;
    for(int i=0; i < ((1024/64) -1); i+=64)
    {
            memcpy(tempBuf, temp, cpyBytes);
            temp += 64;
    }
    }
    now(&end_time);

    printf("time taken by posix_memaligned buffer: %ld \n", (end_time.tv_nsec - st_time.tv_nsec));

    char buf1[1024];        
    temp = buf1;        
    now(&st_time);        
    for(int x=0; x<runs; x++) 
    {        
      temp = buf1;        
      for(int i=0; i < ((1024/64) -1); i+=64)        
     {                
        memcpy(tempBuf, temp, cpyBytes);                
        temp += 64;        
      }          
    }        
    now(&end_time);        
    printf("time taken by standard buffer: %ld \n", (end_time.tv_nsec - st_time.tv_nsec));
    return 0;
}

void now(struct timespec *tnow)
{
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, tnow) <0 )
    {
            printf("error getting time");
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

The disassembly for first loop is

```
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdx        
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rcx        
    leaq    -176(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    memcpy
    addq    $64, -48(%rbp)
    addl    $64, -20(%rbp)
```

The disassembly of second loop is

```
    movq    -40(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    -48(%rbp), %rcx
    leaq    -176(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    memcpy
    addq    $64, -48(%rbp)
    addl    $64, -4(%rbp)
```

Comment: Can you show the disassembly of the two inner loops?

Comment: Well clearly it's got nothing to do with the assembly... hehe

Comment: My version of GCC optimizes the loops to nothing...so they both execute equally fast.  That's on Mac OS X 10.8.2 with `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`.

Comment: You might want to add the CPU you have. How memory alignment affect performance, that depends on CPU model. Many CPU architectures don't even allow unaligned memory access (resulting in "Bus error" fault, crashing the program just like segmentaion fault would), but x86 and x64 do allow it.

Comment: You're measuring time incorrectly. The "struct timespec" is a structure of tv_sec and tv_nsec. In your measurements you completely ignore the seconds part and only subtract the nanoseconds. Suppose start=(1s,7ns), end=(2s, 10ns), then your program will claim that only 3ns have passed.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak you are right, it was intentional, as i was manually keeping the test under a second. But i decided to run longer tests and accomodate both sec and nanoseconds and results are still the same.

Comment: Do note that your buffers on the stack are aligned randomly. Your results could be just be coincidence. Also: sizeof is your friend.

Comment: BTW: this could be a L2 cache effect. The second case could fit into one L2 slot, the first one will need (at least) two, because stack and heap are too far apart.

Comment: @wildplasser ...interesting, i will increase the size to 10MB and try again.

Comment: @wildplasser your hunch was correct. how does CPU decide what should reside in L2 cache. Is there a way to hint CPU to cache some thing in L2 or L1?

Comment: The caches are organised hierarchical. *Every* memory access must go through *both* L1 and L2 cache. At least for data. For instructions can be different. PAE memory (on intel 32/36 bit) is not cacheable, because it does not have a logical addres, only a physical one.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the reason is the relative alignment of the buffers.

`memcpy` works fastest when copying word-aligned data (32/64 bits).
If both buffers are well-aligned, all is OK.
If both buffers are mis-aligned the same way, `memcpy` handles it by copying a small-prefix byte by byte, then running word by word on the remainder.

But if one buffer is word-aligned and the other isn't, there's no way to have both reads and writes word aligned. So `memcpy` still works word by word, but one half of the memory accesses are badly aligned.

If both your stack buffers are unaligned the same way (e.g. both addresses are 8*x+2), but the buffer from `posix_memalign` is aligned, it can explain what you see.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your benchmark:

- Your run-time is too short, hence you may be seeing a lot of noise/jitter.
- If you have CPU frequency scaling enabled the first loop may be executing before the CPU switches into full/turbo frequency. You need to warm up the CPU first or, better, turn off the frequency scaling during benchmarking.
- You may be observing scheduling because you are not running with real-time priority.
- Each run you get only one sample, you'd need at the very least 30 runs to be in a position to make any kind of scientific judgment (a scientific study with one sample is commonly called an anecdote).

Answer (score 0):

When I swapped you measurement blocks - that is, run standard buffer measurement first and `posix_memalign` second, I get exactly opposite results.
In other words, first copy loop for my CPU (Intel Core 2) is almost always slower than second, no matter how aligned they are.

I have tried to `malloc()` standard buffer rather than having it on stack - it almost does not make any difference for speed, first loop is still always slower.

I also tried to `posix_memalign()` your small 64-byte buffer - it did not make any difference.

**EDIT:** I have edited your code to do 3 measurements: posix aligned, malloc'ed, and buffer on stack (see code below).

It turns out that only the very first loop is slow. Any subsequent loop is taking almost exactly the same time (with some small noise).

I believe that we are observing Linux scheduler ramping up CPU clock speed as soon as it sees 100% CPU load.

Results of my run:

```
$ ./readmemory 2000000 5
time taken by posix aligned: 19599140
time taken by std malloc   : 14711350
time taken by std on stack : 14680668
time taken by posix aligned: 14729273
time taken by std malloc   : 14685338
time taken by std on stack : 14839183
time taken by posix aligned: 14709836
time taken by std malloc   : 15551900
time taken by std on stack : 14659350
time taken by posix aligned: 14721298
time taken by std malloc   : 14691732
time taken by std on stack : 14691246
time taken by posix aligned: 14722127
time taken by std malloc   : 15538286
time taken by std on stack : 14723657
```

Updated code:

```
// compile with: g++ readmemory.c -o readmemory -lrt

#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define COPY_BYTES 64

void now(struct timespec *tnow) {
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, tnow) < 0) {
        printf("error getting time");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void measure(char * buf, int runs, const char * msg) {
    char tempBuf[64];
    struct timespec st_time, end_time;
    char * temp;
    now(&st_time);
    for (int x=0; x<runs; x++) {
        temp = buf;
        for (int i=0; i < ((BUF_SIZE/COPY_BYTES) - 1); i+=COPY_BYTES) {
            memcpy(tempBuf, temp, COPY_BYTES);
            temp += COPY_BYTES;
        }
    }
    now(&end_time);
    printf("time taken by %s: %ld\n", msg, end_time.tv_nsec - st_time.tv_nsec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char * buf1;         // posix_memalign'ed
    char * buf2;         // malloc'ed
    char buf3[BUF_SIZE]; // alloc on stack
    int rc = -1;
    int runs;
    int loops;
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./readMemory <runs> <loops>\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    errno = 0;
    runs    = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    if (errno != 0) {
        printf("Invalid number of runs: %s \n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    loops = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);

    rc = posix_memalign((void **)&buf1, COPY_BYTES, BUF_SIZE);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("error in posix_memalign\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    buf2 = (char *) malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    if (buf2 == NULL) {
        printf("error in malloc\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<loops; i++) {
        measure(buf1, runs, "posix aligned");
        measure(buf2, runs, "std malloc   ");
        measure(buf3, runs, "std on stack ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I think we are observing rather complicated ways modern CPUs implement caching.

Comment: I revised the program, so that posix_memalign's loop is run 10 times. I agree with your observation that first loop is always slow, BUT, there after, the result follows the same pattern as described above, where the remainder 9 metrics for posix_memalign loop, though faster than the first loop, are still way higher than the standard buffer loop. Also, the remainder 9 loops dont show much variability as expected. Try running this test with runs=100, 1000, 10000, 100000 and so on, and  you will observe that with smaller runs like 100,000 posix_memalign is way higher than standard buffer.

Comment: Doesn't http://stackoverflow.com/a/13490025/412080 explain what you are observing here?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin how? It suggests that cpu warm up, which i have eliminated now by running both the loops several times and smoothing out any initial slow readings...